# Trello new card created/modified to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, trello, zapier

Trello provides api that can be integrated in google scripts so that if something happens in spreadsheet, we can create/modify cards in appropriate boards.
Also zapier provides similar sort of integrations.

But is the reverse possible? i.e. if some new card gets created or modified, it gets pushed back to google sheet.

I could not find in their api if they have some sort of a listener that listens to card created/modified event(please correct me if I am wrong). So was thinking of alternative ways to do the same.

Comment: Trello has [webhooks](https://trello.com/docs/api/webhook/index.html), but I don't know if it is possible to point them at a google spreadsheet in a meaningful way.  You might have to run an intermediate server.

Comment: Hi, I am also struggling to make this work...
According to Trellos's doc (http://bit.ly/1MdsEY4), when creating a webhook via the API, a HEAD request is sent to the callback url and the webhook is created only if this requests returns a 200 status code.
However, according to http://bit.ly/1LdhKBm, it seems that Google app scripts callback does not support HEAD request and returns a 403 status code...

Comment: The reverse is possible with Zapier; however doing both with Zapier would be difficult as Zapier isn't a sync tool.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround:

1. In the App Script Editor, drop down *Publish* menu and select *Deploy as web app ...*
2. Set *Who has access to the app* to *Anyone* (this limits it to those who have logged in - ie Trello is not logged in).
3. Add the webhook (this will now succeed).
4. Go back to step 2 and this time set it to *Anyone, even anonymous*

Comment: Thank you so much @Mansour ! I've been stuck for hours on that stupid problem. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: For those who're wondering why @Mansour workaround works, it's because Trello validates the webhook by doing an HTTP HEAD. Unfortunately, when your Apps Script is published as a web app with access "Anyone, even anonymous" (which is necessary if you want to allow Trello to make POST requests without having to authenticate) then HTTP HEAD to your Apps Script returns 403 (you can test that in Postman easily). By using the trick above, HTTP HEAD will return 200, which will allow you to register your webhook to Trello. Don't forget to reset access to "Anyone, even anonymous".

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Scripts can be published as webapps.  You can use the built in functions doGet() and doPost() to receive GET and POST events to your webapp. I haven't setup Trello specifically but I do use this to setup webhooks for github.

Here are the docs on pubishing your script as a web app
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

The docs will state that you must return an htmlService or contentService object from a doPost() or doGet(). Most webhooks are looking for a response code, you can simply do a '*return 200;*'  That works fine.

note: missing from the docs is how to access the post body.

```
function doPost(e){
 var postBody = e.postData.getDataAsString();
 // Do something with the postBody Data
 return 200;
}
```